# Can Forms Authentication, Role Management and Data for the WinForm application all work from a single SQL database?

Tags: winforms, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, user-roles

With reference to this Question: [Can Forms Authentication, Role Management and Data for the website all work from a single SQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323785/can-forms-authentication-role-management-and-data-for-the-website-all-work-from), I require a single Database but for WinForm applications. I need Roles and User Management and I'm upgrading a legacy application so Users Table preexists and has some data. I'll need to import that data.

Environment: Windows 7 Pro 64-bit, SQL Server 2008 EE, Visual Studio 2010, C#, .NET 4.0, and Windows Forms

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is completely possible. All you need to do is run the script to register the required tables in your database.

### [This is easy to do using the ASP.NET SQL Server Registration Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

The other data tables do not have to follow any specific schema and will not conflict with your ASP.NET tables unless you introduce some problematic data table relationships.

Comment: Well, that was the easy bit. The tables were created and now I need to know where to go now? Do I have to add a ASP.NET project to the solution? How can I authenticate and specify custom Roles and Users?

Comment: Look at the `Membership` and `Roles` APIs.  They are static classes located in the `System.Web.Security` namespace.  Those, along with the corresponding `web.config` sections, should have everything you need.

Comment: `System.Web.Security` and `web.config` works well in a ASP.NEt project. I'm attempting the same in a WinForm and I have `app.config`

Comment: It should work the same way, you might need to configure the authentication configuration section in the app.config